# How to handle posting payload in POST method even if one field is missing in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have implemented a post method with Django rest framework, the problem with the post method is that when posting one is required to include all the required fields of the payload so as the request to be successful. How do I make it possible to allow one to post successfully if anyone field is missing from the payload?

Answer (score 2):

if i correctly understand you question. You can choose which field must be required or not in serializer

```
class CompanyRoomTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = CompanyRoomType
        fields = ('description', 'type_name', 'guests', 'rooms', 'one_beds', 'two_beds')
        extra_kwargs = {'description': {'required': True}, 'type_name': {'required': False}}
```